# Adding a CSS folder on Sublime Texts side bar with a main.css and normalize.css file

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I installed the AdvancedNewFile plugin and am trying to create a css folder relative with following files inside of it:

This code is included in  in my html file. If I add code to main.css it doest do anything within my html file because there is no relative css path/folder set up in the side bar with both the files inside of it.

Any thoughts on how to create a css folder, get these 2 files inside of it and how to sync all these documents (html, normalize.css, main.css) together so that my css code works within my html page?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">     These are the files I want inside the css folder.

Comment: I understand this is basic code. The code is not my issue here. My issue is creating files and file paths with Sublime Text. @Hanoncs

Comment: @Hanoncs  its not a duplicate. you are missing the whole question here. This has nothing to do with html or css. It has everything to do with figuring out how to create folders with file paths to the actual files themselves like css within sublime text